# Self Hosted Owin Web API 2 application: How do I start the web app with arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, owin, self-hosting

I am trying to add a REST API to a console application using self hosted `Owin Web API 2`.

```
// Starting the REST API
string baseAddress = "http://localhost:8000/";
WebApp.Start<WebApi.WebApiStartup>(url: baseAddress);
```

I am relying on previously instantiated objects to access a third party API (used in the console application).
Since the Web API mimics the console application behavior it should use the same objects. Thus my question: How do I pass those objects to the constructor of the web app?

Once the `webapp` started I use unity to Inject the objects to the controllers:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterInstance<AggregatePosition>(position);
HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
```

in this example the object "position" should be passed to the web app at initialization. Is there a way to Inject it there?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding your question correctly. Are you asking how to instantiate an object in your console app and pass that instance into the webAPI? If that's what you are asking then the answer is don't do that even if you can figure out a way. Call the API to get the data you need to then update the instance in the console app. Your API should work as it's own entity with no knowledge of your other app.

Comment: Pass it via command line at command prompt and grab it from `args[]` in the `Main` function.

Comment: @StephenBrickner Yes, you understood right. The thing is the API will keep streaming data my way and both the console application and the webapp should be able to access the API singleton all the time. So you are suggesting that I instantiate the singleton at the web app and then pass it to the console application?

Comment: @LexLi Stephen understood right. I need singletons to be accessible at the same time by the web app exposing the REST API and the console application (exposing a socket interface). Can you elaborate your solution?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do will work. Once you make a request to the api you don't have an open connection that will stay open while it's streaming. WebAPI is a request/response message pump basically. If you make a call to the webAPI and it starts streaming you run the risk of your request timing out before it completes. I would just have your web app call the API to get your data with an async method so it returns the data once it completes. The API doesn't need to know why it's getting the data or who/what needs it, it just gets a request to give that data to what asks for it.

Comment: @StephenBrickner well the singleton keeps getting updated independently. I just need the web api to respond with the state of the singleton at any given moment. I do not intend to call the API when the rest service is called.